# coefficient of simple regression model in bayesian model

Tags: regression, bayesian

I have a simple regression model y=ax+b estimated from a dataset. I would like to estimate the confidence that: a=0 and b>0. How can I do it using bayedian model.

thank you
Ariel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bayesian model fit by using MCMC, you can easily get coefficients across all simulations (or simulations after convergence). Then there should be no hard to calculate a CI or quantile for these parameters.